# Constructors that take different sizes of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I can do this:

```
struct foo{
    foo(std::array<double, 3>){}
    foo(std::array<double, 4>){}
}
```

I would like to do this:

```
struct foo{
    foo(double A[3]){}
    foo(double A[4]){}
}
```

Which, of course, does not work.

This involves legacy code with a lot of 3 and 4 element double arrays.  I desire to construct a class that contains 4 doubles from either 3 or 4 element arrays, and initialize the 4th double with a constant value when constructing from a 3 element array.  When I initialize from a 4 element array, I just copy in the 4 elements.

So, I would like to make constructor(s) to recognize:

```
double something[3];
```

from:

```
double something_else[4];
```

The best I can think of is to add another parameter to the constructor to distinguish between the two.

```
class foo{
    foo(double A[4], bool only_3 = false){}

    foo(double *A, size_t n = 4){}
}
```

Any better ideas?

(As time permits, I'll chase out all the raw arrays, but for now I have to deal with it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays can be passed by reference.  If you have

```
struct foo{
    foo(double (&A)[3]){}
    foo(double (&A)[4]){}
};
```

Then `foo` can only be constructed from an array of size 3 or size 4.  This does stop you from accepting pointers though so

```
double bar = new double[4];
foo f(bar);
```

wont work.

Comment: I will tinker with this to see where it gets me.  It is unfortunate that it kills pointers.

Comment: @ttemple You can add an overload for pointers, it's just that you'll have to write logic in it for how to handle arrays of not the correct size.

Comment: if I add foo(double *p) it grabs everything.  What is the correct way to add it so that the others still get called?

Comment: @ttemple It gets a little tricky.  What you need to to is to tell the compiler to only use the pointer overload when the thing passed in is really a pointer and not an array that can decay into a pointer.  To do that you need to make the constructor a template and use SFINAE.  You can see that working here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/471aa48d5247f3d9

Answer (score 1):

You can make your constructors accept references to the arrays:

```
struct foo {
    foo(const double (&A)[3]) {}
    foo(const double (&A)[4]) {}
};
```

And if the functions are similar enough, you could make a template accepting both versions:

```
struct foo {
    template<size_t N, std::enable_if_t<N == 3 || N == 4, bool> = true>
    constexpr foo(const double (&A)[N]) noexcept {
        std::copy(std::begin(A), std::end(A), values);
        if constexpr(N == 3) values[3] = ... // some constant;
    }

    double values[4];
};
```

If you need to accept dynamically allocated arrays (`double*`) with sizes known at compile time, you could create a constructor template using tags to assert that the sizes used are acceptable.

```
struct foo {
    template<size_t N, std::enable_if_t<N == 3 || N == 4, bool> = true>
    struct size_tag_t {};

    // convenience tag instances
    static constexpr size_tag_t<3> three_tag{};
    static constexpr size_tag_t<4> four_tag{};

    template<size_t N>
    constexpr foo(const double* A, size_tag_t<N>) noexcept {
        std::copy(A, A + N, values);
        if constexpr(N == 3) values[3] = ... // some constant;
    }

    double values[4];
};

//...
constexpr size_t THREE = 3;
double* da3 = new double[THREE];
foo pthree1(da3, foo::size_tag_t<THREE>{});
// or
foo pthree2(da3, foo::three_tag);
```